# Embed applet in a CHM or any other e-book format

Tags: java, applet, chm

I would like to embed and a java applet from a CHM file that I wish to create out of the HTML files I have.

I have HTML files with java applets embedded. When I tried converting it into a CHM with some CHM converter, the applets were gone. I just got the remaining part other than the applet.

Is there any way I can get the CHM(or anyother e-book format) files with the applets embedded inside?

Comment: As an aside, what is the applet supposed to contribute to an e-book *or* a Windows help file?

Comment: The applet just runs an algorithm and generates a graph.

Comment: Get a static image of the graph and include the image instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  E-books typically do not support a JRE, so it is no surprise that applet elements are stripped when converting from to HTML to CHM or e-book formats.